# what size trowel should I use?

Tags: kitchens

I have an arabesque ceramic mosaic mesh sheet to apply as a kitchen backsplash. It's 10.5 in width x 15.5 in length x 8 mm thick. I am a first time DYI and appreciate your advice.

Thank you,

Jaz

Answer (score 1):

1/4 or 1/8th inch notched trowel.  Really it depends on how thick the tiles are.  If they are thick mosaic tiles I would go with 1/4th inch.  If on the thinner side you want 1/8th.

You want good coverage but this is just a backsplash.  So looks and getting too much thinset in the cracks trumps the other stuff.  If I had a perfectly flat wall I would almost always use 1/8th.  You can give yourself more wiggle room with 1/4th but this also may make your install take longer.

Comment: Sounds like how I would do it. Make to use spacers to keep all the grout lines the same width this is where some DIY try to save 3 bucks and the job looks like a DIY.+